# Can you say“ 何が貴方のお名前はですか”？Or does 何 have to come before です？

Tags: grammar, syntax, particle-が, copula, word-order

I’ve read that what’s your name is “貴方のお名前は何ですか“ but can you also put 何 to the beginning or is that incorrect? So can it be: 何が貴方のおなまえはですか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as a basic rule, the polite copula です must be preceded by a (pro)noun or an adjective (eg 犬です, 元気です). お名前はですか is plain ungrammatical because です is directly preceded by the topic marker は.

How about 何があなたのお名前ですか? This is actually grammatical, but almost always nonsensical, because this uses [exhaustive-listing-*ga*](https://www.imabi.net/theparticlegai.htm) and thus sounds like "What is the one that is your name?" This question may be used in a very special context, for example, when you are irritated after talking with a confused person who is referring to himself with various different names. Otherwise, you must say 名前は何ですか.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more thing: how about “何あなたのお名前ですか”？

Comment: @SiroCaruso 何あなた is ungrammatical to me without a lengthy absurdist sci-fi background I wasn't able to describe in the 500 character comment limit.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.